# Cannot visualize ImageField in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, image, django-rest-framework, download, imagedownload

I have a model with an ImageField:

```
image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True, null=True)
```

I did include it in my serializer in this way:

```
image_url = serializers.ImageField(required=False, use_url=True)
```

This is my viewset:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Product.objects.order_by('-id')
serializer_class = ProductSerializer
parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
permission_classes = [
    permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()
```

The media root and url:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path("users/", include("user.urls")),
path("products/", include("products.urls")),
path("utils/", include("utils.urls")),
path("auth/", include("djoser.urls")),
path("auth/", include("djoser.urls.jwt")),
path("graphql/", csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(schema=schema, graphiql=True))),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It get listed properly:

[image]

But the problem is that once I click on the url of the image (that is inside the media folder), it shows me a 404 error in this url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/base_bWxtftQ.png. But the image is in that folder.

Comment: Are you using `python manage.py runserver` to run the application? And I am guessing your Frontend is not Django. In that case it can't reach those urls in the absence of a webserver such as Nginx or Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did append the static content to the api urlpattern. Instead of that is necessary append the static content to the root urlpattern (that one defined in the ROOT_URLCONF of the settings).